# How to programmatically detect when Apple complies with governmental restrictions?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, emoji, great-firewall-of-china

Some iPhones are under governmental restrictions. For instance, the Taiwanese flag will sometimes be censored at system level to block freedom of speech. Source: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-censors-taiwan-flag-on-iphones-in-china.2034425/

How to detect programmatically if your app is running on such restricted iPhone?

[missing Unicode for Taiwanese flag](https://forums.macrumors.com/proxy.php?image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgsafe.org%2F27fbd084e8.jpg&hash=32cfb8a842801b209bb507d2467e6e1c)

Comment: 1. Render a string containing that flag emoji, 2. Use some sort of image recognition to detect if the rendered image looks like the flag or that X icon, 3. If it looks like the X icon, the phone is restricted.

Comment: What is the use-Case for detecting this restriction? The restriction occurs at the store level.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the iOS for China is missing the actually flag of Taiwanese flag. It’s up to the developer of the app, before they publish it in a country, they are not breaking that country’s law.